# Julia using argmax to return index within a row of a matrix instead of a CartesianIndex

Tags: julia

Say I have a matrix

```
X = [1 2 3 4; 1 4 3 2];
```

I would like to find the argmax of each row of this matrix, relative to that row and not the index of the entry within the entirety of X. Meaning that I want the output of argmax(X, dims = (2)) to be a vector,

```
[4, 2];
```

but the current output is an array of CartesianIndex

```
[CartesianIndex(1, 4), CartesianIndex(2, 2)];
```

Is there a way to specify this in the argmax function or to transform the output efficiently to my desired state?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `eachrow` to iterate over rows of a matrix:

```
julia> argmax.(eachrow(X))
2-element Vector{Int64}:
 4
 2
```